# Codeigniter how to add a textarea if a certain value is selected in dropdown

Tags: database, forms, codeigniter

I have a dropdown that is populated by my database so what I want is if a user wants to add another item but cant find the category in the dropdown he would select "other" from the list and then will create a new category for that particular item

view

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags --> 

        <title>Add Item</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ICON.PNG">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">


    <div class="row" >


        <div class="col-md-10">
            <br>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">



                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">

                            <?php echo form_open_multipart('add_products/do_upload'); ?>



                            <center>        <?php if (validation_errors()): ?>

                                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert" style="width: 700px;">
                                        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif ?>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" style=" color: white"></label>

                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Product Image</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <input type="file" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="userfile">
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <br> <br>
                                <br>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" style=" color: white"></label>

                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Product Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ex. coffee"
                                               name="name"
                                               value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>">
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <br> <br>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" style=" color: white"></label>

                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ex.  brewed drink from roasted coffee"
                                               name="description"
                                               value="<?php echo set_value('description'); ?>">
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <br> <br>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" style=" color: white"></label>

                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="ex. P180"
                                               name="price"
                                               value="<?php echo set_value('price'); ?>">
                                    </div>

                                </div>       
                                <br> <br>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" style=" color: white"></label>

                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">

                                 <select class="form-control" name="prod_category">
            <?php 

            foreach($category as $row)
            { 
              echo '<option value="'.$row->category.'">'.$row->category.'</option>';

            }
            ?>
                                     <option>Other</option>

            </select></div>

                                </div>    


                                <br> <br>

                                <button style="margin-left: 75px; width: 320px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>

                                </form>
                            <?php echo form_close() ?></div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>


    </div>



</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

controller"

```
function index()
 {
      $this->load->helper(array('form'));
   if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
   {
     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
     $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
     $data['category'] = $this->User->get_category();
     $this->load->view('add_products',$data);
   }
```

model:

```
public function get_category(){
        $p = $this->db->query("select category from product_category");
        $p1 = $p->result();
        return $p1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html for your select box :-

```
 <select class="form-control select" name="prod_category">
                <?php 

                foreach($category as $row)
                { 
                  echo '<option value="'.$row->category.'">'.$row->category.'</option>';

                }
                ?>
                                         <option value="lllvnjs">Other</option>

                </select>
<div class="append"></div>
```

then jquery's change for your select box(Dont forget to add jquery before this in your markup )

```
$("select").change(function(){
   if($(this).val() == "lllvnjs")
{
   $(".append").append('<input type="text" value="" name="other_category" />');
}
});
```

In last when submits your form check this condition in your controller

```
$category = $_POST["prod_category"];
if($category  == "lllvnjs")
{
$category = $_POST["other_category"];
}
```

And insert this in your database Or whatever you want to do with this just do :)

Comment: where do I put the last code?
i tried your code but when I insert an existing category it returns 0 but the other category works fine

Comment: @Christian Last code put it in your controller where you submitting your form
And insert this as $this->db->insert("product_category",array("category"=>$category))

Answer (score 1):

You can use change() in jquery for adding a textarea to your UI

```
$("#category").on("change",function() {
    var selectedcat = $(this).val();
    if(selectedcat == -1)
    {
        $("#newcategory").show();
    }
  });
```

Just refer the Filddle below
https://jsfiddle.net/5ueco3s9/

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! but if I chose a category that's already on the list its not being inserted into the database

Comment: it should not insert right i am not clear with you, if a category is already there then why do you need it to insert again and again it will be lead to data duplication right ?